# Question about polymorphism and mulitipule inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I hope to store the data in three different ways:

1.store to a `std::string`

2.write to file descriptor

3.both of the above

And I hope to use a uniform interface for these three different methods.

I wrote a simple code sippet to achieve the said goals. The first & second  are easy indeed, but for the third I am stuck.

Please pay attention to the comment in the code snippet below, which is what the compiler complains if `STORE_BY_FD_AND_STRING` is defined.

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/hs719aa3s):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
 
class DataStorage {
public:
  DataStorage(int total_count):total_count_(total_count){};
  virtual int Store(const char *buffer, int count) = 0;
  virtual ~DataStorage(){};

protected:
  int total_count_;
};

class DataStorageByStr : public DataStorage {
public:
  DataStorageByStr(std::string &str) : str_(str), DataStorage(0){};
  int Store(const char *buffer, int count)
  {
    str_ += std::string(buffer, count);
    total_count_ += count;
    return 0;
  };

protected:
  std::string &str_;
};

class DataStorageByFd : public DataStorage {
public:
  DataStorageByFd(int &fd):fd_(fd), DataStorage(0){};
  int Store(const char *buffer, int count)
  {
     int ret = write(fd_, buffer, count);
     if(ret > 0)
     {
         total_count_ += ret;
     }

     return ret;
  };

protected:
  int &fd_;
};

class DataStorageByStrAndFd : public DataStorageByStr, public DataStorageByFd {
public:
  DataStorageByStrAndFd(std::string &str, int &fd):DataStorageByStr(str), DataStorageByFd(fd) {}
  
  int Store(const char *buffer, int count)
  {
    int ret1 = DataStorageByStr::Store(buffer, count);
    int ret2 = DataStorageByFd::Store(buffer, count);

    return ((0==ret1) && (0==ret2))?0:-1;
  }
};

int StoreSomeData(DataStorage *pstorage, const std::string data_to_store)
{
    return pstorage->Store(data_to_store.data(), data_to_store.length());
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::string str{"storing the string to std::string works !"};
        std::string data;

        DataStorage *pstorage = new DataStorageByStr(data);
        StoreSomeData(pstorage, str);

        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::string str{"storing the string to fd works !"};
        int fd = 1;

        DataStorage *pstorage = new DataStorageByFd(fd);
        StoreSomeData(pstorage, str);
    }



#ifdef STORE_BY_FD_AND_STRING
    {
        std::string str{"thanks for your attention for this matter!"};

        std::string data;
        int fd = 1;

        DataStorage *pstorage = new DataStorageByStrAndFd(str, fd); //The compiler complain that 'DataStorage' is an ambiguous base of 'DataStorageByStrAndFd'
        StoreSomeData(pstorage, str);
    }
#endif
}
```

Any sugestion to achieve all the aforementioned goals?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of virtual inheritance. It gets a bad rap in some places, but I believe it's one of the distinct and one of the most powerful parts of C++. This can be done by virtually inheriting `DataStorage`, then multiply-inheriting from both subclasses, and then simply having `DataStorageByStrAndFd::Store()` invoke both parent classes' `Store()`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ... and one more required addition is to *explicitly* call `DataStorage(0)` in the constructor 'initializer-list' of `DataStorageByStrAndFd`. Could even be an answer?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [Seems does not work](https://godbolt.org/z/xqss7534c). Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the details of how virtual class inheritance works, and the requirement to explicitly construct all virtually-inherited classes that do not have a default constructor (or even if they do, but a non-default constructor is required by the most-derived class, as suggested by Adrian). See your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: Virtual inheritance already mentioned in the comments. But maybe would be even better to just define the free functions for writing to string and file, and then just invoke them in your overloads. This way you don't duplicate your code and you avoid multiple inheritance.

Comment: Personally, I'd derive `DataStorageByStrAndFd` from `DataStorage` directly, and give it data members of types `DataStorageByStr` and `DataStorageByFd`. I don't see any benefit from multiple inheritance here. `DataStorageByStrAndFd::Store` can forward to data members just as well as base classes.

Comment: Just like Igor says except you have to derive from DataStorage. Because as the compiler says otherwise it's unclear which path to take to get to the DataStorage base class.

Comment: @JaMiT I have done it.See ***Please pay attention to the comment in the code snippet below, which is what the compiler complains if STORE_BY_FD_AND_STRING is defined.***

Comment: @pptaszni Sorry, I can't get your idea. Could you please show me a simple example to fully understand that?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for pointing out that. It's a really a new/good idea to me. If I understand you correctly, the code snippet should look like [this one](https://godbolt.org/z/9j9xhrxEz). But there is a problem when `DataStorageByStrAndFd` is directly derived from `DataStorage`. There would be an extra `DataStorage::total_count_` for `DataStorageByStrAndFd`, which seems useless because both `DataStorageByStrAndFd::storage_by_str_` and `DataStorageByStrAndFd::storage_by_fd_`  already have `DataStorage::total_count_` of theirselves. If I missing something, please let me know.

Comment: @John Weird. You request people to pay attention to something without telling them why, and people ignore that request. Also, you hide important information in a spot where it requires scrolling in two directions to find it. It's like you are trying to make it hard for people to help you. I would expect to see something as important as the error message prominently displayed before the code. But I see now that I was wrong -- you did include the error message. So I'll remove my close vote. I'll replace it with a downvote for the obfuscation (i.e. lack of clarity).

Comment: I don't see why `DataStorage` should have a `total_count_` member in the first place, when a) it's unable to maintain it, and b) it doesn't publicly expose it. It's unusual for an interface to have data members. In fact, I don't see why any of the classes involved need `total_count_` member - maintaining it is pure busywork.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  You see  `total_count_ ` is used to calculate how many bytes have been passed to `::Store()` method. If it's bad to make `total_count_` as a member variable, How to make it better?

Comment: How many bytes have been passed, or how many bytes have been written? Your implementation of `DataStorageByStrAndFd` effectively double-counts bytes passed to `Store`. In any case, the number is computed but never used for anything. Nor can it be used, as none of the classes involved make it available to callers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik *Your implementation of `DataStorageByStrAndFd` effectively **double-counts** bytes passed to Store*. I **start to realize** that it's really a problem indeed. But I don't find a good way to solve this problem(you see, it's reasonable that `total_count_` is in the base class since both `DataStorageByStr` and `DataStorageByFd` need this property). [I add a method to get the `total_count_ `](https://godbolt.org/z/rGeK78GsP)

Comment: If `DataStorageByStr` and `DataStorageByFd` need the byte count for their own internal purposes, but the user of `DataStorage` is not interested in that number, then it sounds like an internal implementation detail that doesn't belong to the base class. The fact that some (but not all) implementations of `DataStorage` need it appears to be pure coincidence.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If I understand you correctly, the code snippet should be rewritten like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rqEdKx6de). The said method should not in implementated the base class. Am I right?

Comment: Again - personally, I'd derive `DataStorageByStrAndFd` from `DataStorage` and give it data members of types `DataStorageByStr` and `DataStorageByFd`. I don't see a reason for multiple inheritance here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sam Varshavchik @Adrian Mole. This code snippet works.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
 
class DataStorage {
public:
  DataStorage(int total_count):total_count_(total_count){};
  virtual int Store(const char *buffer, int count) = 0;
  virtual ~DataStorage(){};

protected:
  int total_count_;
};

class DataStorageByStr : virtual public  DataStorage {
public:
  DataStorageByStr(std::string &str) : str_(str), DataStorage(0){};
  int Store(const char *buffer, int count)
  {
    str_ += std::string(buffer, count);
    total_count_ += count;
    return 0;
  };

protected:
  std::string &str_;
};

class DataStorageByFd :virtual public  DataStorage {
public:
  DataStorageByFd(int &fd):fd_(fd), DataStorage(0){};
  int Store(const char *buffer, int count)
  {
     int ret = write(fd_, buffer, count);
     if(ret > 0)
     {
         total_count_ += ret;
     }

     return ret;
  };

protected:
  int &fd_;
};

class DataStorageByStrAndFd : public  DataStorageByStr, public  DataStorageByFd {
public:
  DataStorageByStrAndFd(std::string &str, int &fd):DataStorageByStr(str), DataStorageByFd(fd), DataStorage(0)
  {
    
  }
  
  int Store(const char *buffer, int count)
  {
    int ret1 = DataStorageByStr::Store(buffer, count);
    int ret2 = DataStorageByFd::Store(buffer, count);

    return ((0==ret1) && (0==ret2))?0:-1;
  }
};

int StoreSomeData(DataStorage *pstorage, const std::string data_to_store)
{
    return pstorage->Store(data_to_store.data(), data_to_store.length());
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::string str{"storing the string to std::string works !"};
        std::string data;

        DataStorage *pstorage = new DataStorageByStr(data);
        StoreSomeData(pstorage, str);

        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::string str{"storing the string to fd works !"};
        int fd = 1;

        DataStorage *pstorage = new DataStorageByFd(fd);
        StoreSomeData(pstorage, str);
    }



#ifndef STORE_BY_FD_AND_STRING
    {
        std::string str{"thanks for your attention for this matter!"};

        std::string data;
        int fd = 1;

        DataStorage *pstorage = new DataStorageByStrAndFd(str, fd); //The compiler complain that 'DataStorage' is an ambiguous base of 'DataStorageByStrAndFd'
        StoreSomeData(pstorage, str);
    }
#endif
}
```

[Explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance#:%7E:text=Virtual%20inheritance%20is%20a%20C,inherited%20by%20grandchild%20derived%20classes.):

[image]

Virtual inheritance is a C++ technique that ensures only one copy of a base class's member variables are inherited by grandchild derived classes. Without virtual inheritance, if two classes B and C inherit from a class A, and a class D inherits from both B and C, then D will contain two copies of A's member variables: one via B, and one via C. These will be accessible independently, using scope resolution.

Instead, if classes B and C inherit virtually from class A, then objects of class D will contain only one set of the member variables from class A.

This feature is most useful for multiple inheritance, as it makes the virtual base a common subobject for the deriving class and all classes that are derived from it. This can be used to avoid the diamond problem by clarifying ambiguity over which ancestor class to use, as from the perspective of the deriving class (D in the example above) the virtual base (A) acts as though it were the direct base class of D, not a class derived indirectly through a base (B or C).